# What are the best online homebrew retailers in Australia?

Tags: equipment, ingredients, shopping

I've been looking for good homebrew ingredient and equipment retailers in Australia and would like some recommendations. If you have recommendations for online retailers that have the follow qualities they would be greatly appreciated:

- Are based in Australia
- Have a good, easy to navigate website
- Have a good range of equipment and ingredients
- Have good prices
- Can ship quickly

Answer (score 3):

Your question may be a bit too localized.  Hopefully an actual Aussie will reply instead of a Yank that's only been there.

The nicest looking website I found was [The Country Brewer](http://www.countrybrewer.com.au/).

If you wish to discuss brewing with your fellow Aussies, [then there is this forum](http://www.aussiehomebrewer.com/forum/index.php).

I found [this site called Dave's Homebrew that carries supplies](https://daveshomebrew.com.au/), however the site seems a bit amateurish.

[If you are in South Australia, this site seems pretty good](http://www.brewcraftsa.com.au/).

Anyway, I hope this helps a bit.  As I said, it may behoove you visit that forum in the second link to speak with fellow Aussies instead of a worldwide web page that may not have the local insight you are looking for.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of where you are, check out your local (or at least closest) home brew stores and ask them if they have a website.  It turns out that even my little old local has one!

I'm in Western Australia so my advice is certainly biased.  Here's a few places I've used or at least heard good things about.

1. [TWOC](http://www.homebru.com.au/) - My local, has absolutely everything & great advice if you need it (the guy is an Oracle)
2. [BrewCraft](http://www.westbrew.com.au/) - A WA chain store, mainly still supplies & extract kit packs
3. [Ellerslie Hop](http://www.ellersliehop.com.au/) - An Australian hop farm (order by email, minimum 500g)
4. [KegsOnline](http://www.kegsonline.com.au/) - Aussie keg equipment supplier
5. [Minikeg](http://minikeg.net.au/) - Aussie mini-keg (5L) retailer, the kegs are imported but delivery is still quick
6. [Brew Celler](http://www.brewcellar.com.au/stores.asp) - Not used these guys but this link has a whole bunch of stores around AU including websites, you may be able to find somewhere local to you
7. [SedEx](http://sedexbrewing.com/) - These cool sediment filters for bottled beer are an Aussie invention too I believe (NT?)
8. [Dog Beer](http://www.dogbeer.com.au/) - ***What?***

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I am a noob, but have done similar research and can offer the following two links which haven't been mentioned yet:

- [www.liquorcraft.com.au](http://www.liquorcraft.com.au) - Their website is pretty amateur but they have 3 stores in Melbourne. I visited the Richmond store last week and had no complaints. The man was friendly enough although I'm not in a position to judge his knowledge level as I myself am a total noob.
- [www.grainandgrape.com.au](http://www.grainandgrape.com.au) - I haven't been to this store personally (yet) but their website is very good and I have had them recommended to me by an acquaintance who has been home brewing for a few years now. I plan to attend a free brew day at their store in a couple of weeks.

Hope this helps!